# changing function-parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script

Would like to check the parameters passed to a function and replace not specified ones or the ones which "I dont like". For that, I've done the following (The reason why I want to use `arguments` is that I want to have a generic function doing that) (same results with node.js, just change Logger to console):

```
function argtest (x,y,z) {
  Logger.log ("at begin x="+x+", y="+y+", z="+z);
  arguments.length=3; // found this somewhere, doesn't help
  arguments[0]="a";
  arguments[1]="b";
  arguments[2]="c";
  Logger.log ("arguments now:");
  for (var i in arguments) {
    Logger.log ("arguments["+i+"]="+arguments[i]);
  }
  Logger.log ("at end x="+x+", y="+y+", z="+z);
}
function callArgTest () {
  argtest ();
  argtest (1,2,3);
}
```

So the result of calling `callArgTest` is:

```
Logger.log([at begin x=undefined, y=undefined, z=undefined, []])
Logger.log([arguments now:, []])
Logger.log([arguments[0]=a, []])
Logger.log([arguments[1]=b, []])
Logger.log([arguments[2]=c, []])
Logger.log([at end x=undefined, y=undefined, z=undefined, []])
Logger.log([at begin x=1, y=2, z=3, []])
Logger.log([arguments now:, []])
Logger.log([arguments[0]=a, []])
Logger.log([arguments[1]=b, []])
Logger.log([arguments[2]=c, []])
Logger.log([at end x=a, y=b, z=c, []])
```

So the parameters x,y,z only change, when they were initially specified. In the first case (calling `argtest` without parameters) they remain undefined even after assigning values to arguments. So what is missing here to make it work? Note that I dont want to touch x,y,z. Instead in the final implementation I want to pass the arguments to a function which works on them.

Comment: Currently, you're successfully changing `arguments[n]`, but it's not affecting `x`, `y`, or `z`. Why don't you refer to `x`, `y`, `z` using the `arguments[n]` notation?

Comment: What browser is this? I'm able to assign values to `arguments` even when the function is called without arguments. This is in Chrome.

Comment: @LarsH Hmm. x, y, and z are affected if they are specified when the function is called (second call to argtest), simply by changing arguments[0..2], so that's what I want to achieve even when they are not specified (calling `atest()`)

Comment: @Vivin This is google apps script, which is using javascript as language, but it's not a browser environment (no window, no document)

Comment: @Vivin Yes, its possible to assign in that case, but it's not reflected in the parameters x,y,z, so I just think I'm missing something. Also checked it with node.js, shows the same behaviour.

Comment: @pbhd My mistake; I should have paid attention to the tags. :)

Comment: @pbhd Just curious. Why do you even bother with arguments that aren't listed in the signature? As for setting defaults for missing args, I think Jonathan gave you the answer you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, when calling `argtest()`, `arguments` doesn't actually have a `"0"` property to refer to `x`, or `"1"` for `y`, etc.:

```
argtest()      => arguments = { "length": 0 }
argtest(1,2,3) => arguments = { "length": 3, "0": x, "1": y, "2": z }
```

The definition of that reference is described in step `11.c` of [ES5 10.6](http://es5.github.com/#x10.6), which defines getters and setters for each "index" of `arguments`, but is limited by both the number of arguments named and the number of arguments passed.

Regarding your intent:

> *I want to throw in into an existing implementation at the beginning of functions a call to a function which simply takes the arguments and some defaults as parameter, e.g. `defaults (arguments, "string=nana", "number=4")`*

You'll probably find something like this easier:

```
function argTest(x, y, z) {
    x = typeof x !== 'undefined' ? x : ...;
    y = typeof y !== 'undefined' ? y : ...;
    // etc.
}
```

What you want to do is possible with ES5, but would mean defining your own "arguments" object with getters and setters for each "index" and named argument, whether passed a value or not, via [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)/[`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) or [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get)/[`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/set) -- and, I wouldn't consider this "*simply*":

```
function argtest(x, y, z) {
    defaults({
        length: argtest.length,

        get '0'() { return x; },
        set '0'(val) { x = val; },

        get '1'() { return y; },
        set '1'(val) { y = val; },

        get '2'() { return z; },
        set '2'(val) { z = val; }
    }, ...);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this works, but, huh, yes thats not simple. I thought the arguments-object is somehow tied by black magic to the parameters, but it reflects the currently passed parameters. So now I know better. Wer nicht fragt bleibt dumm.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
arguments[0]="a";
arguments[1]="b";
arguments[2]="c";
```

why don't you add

```
x = arguments[0];
y = arguments[1];
z = arguments[2];
```

?
I imagine there's some reason why this doesn't meet your goals, but I guess I need a more realistic example in order to see what really would meet your goals.

Comment: Nah, then I could just work with the x,y,z parameterlist. I want to throw in into an existing implementation at the beginning of functions a call to a function which simply takes the arguments and some defaults as parameter, e.g. `defaults (arguments, "string=nana", "number=4")`, so specifying the names of the actual parameters would somehow add unneccessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

And then work with `args`? You could pass `args` into other functions are you need. Let me know if this helps you out, or if I'm barking up the wrong tree.